# GL_LINEAR texture mapping not giving smooth transition

Tags: android, opengl-es, texture-mapping

In case of video playback, if I am using GL_LINEAR and if my video starts with a black frame, then I dont get a smooth transition from that black frame to next frame. Image attached. Some white / colored dots and lines appear as shown. After this, video plays normally. Has anybody noticed or have solution for this.?

```
GLES20.glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
```

[image]

Comment: What does linear interpolation have to do with two different video frames? It's used for filtering pixels within a single texture, so I'm not sure it does what you think it does if you are expecting interpolation between two textures.

Can you post a more complete example of what you are doing / expecting to happen? It's not really clear from your question.

Comment: Got the issue. As @Isogen74 pointed out, it had nothing to do with GL_LINEAR. Issue was that luminance (Y) value was going out of bounds ie: outside 0-1 range for some pixels. that was the core reason. Not sure though how it can go out of range.